# AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm doing a selenium program that can enter to my email, but I'm having problems with a `By`, and it cannot be `By.name("")` or that seems.

Here is the mentioned part of the code: (running on windows 7):

```
psswd = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.name, "password")))
psswd.send_keys("MyPassword")
```

Comment: `print(type(By))`

Comment: @JacobIRR Why? Where?

Comment: anywhere that will tell us what By actually is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You need to make a simple change as follows:

- You need to replace `name` with **`NAME`**

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
psswd = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
psswd.send_keys("MyPassword")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this error then there would be some exceptions like:

1. you are using By.name perhaps u should use By.NAME
2. you may getting list of objects!
3. you may not imported `By`, to import it write `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

or i suggest you to Use `find_elements_by_xpath` to locate your item in more effective way
here is sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.facebook.com')
msg = 'KA_ME_HA_ME_HAAA'
username = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
username[0].send_keys(msg)
browser.close()
```